# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not resolve PropertyFilter with id 'filterProfile'; no FilterProvider configured

Tags: json, jersey

I have done dynamic filtering on my POJO(profile) object. Filtering logic works fine.Need to return the filtered object as response. But facing issue (MappableException)  in jersey layer , when returning profile object.

Can someone please guide me on this.

### Filter Logic code:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()  .addFilter("filterProfile",SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(set1))
            .addFilter("filterUserDetails", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(set2)).setFailOnUnknownId(false);  

    ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(filters);
    try{            
       // Printing the filtered json object
        filteredJson = writer.writeValueAsString(profile);
    }
```

### POJO:

@JsonFilter("filterProfile")

```
public class Profile {  

    @JsonProperty("session")
    private Session session;
```

### Error:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can
>   not resolve PropertyFilter with id 'filterProfile'; no FilterProvider
>   configured    at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:312)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.findPropertyFilter(StdSerializer.java:441)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFieldsFiltered(BeanSerializerBase.java:731)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:153)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:292)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1429)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:951)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.writeTo(ProviderBase.java:625)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has intetion to filter the properties on serialization, so even if it didn't throw any exceptions, the filter won't work because it is missing this line:

```
mapper.addMixIn(Object.class, Profile.class);
```

However, you said "Filtering logic works fine". Taking that into account,
please, post a minimally-working code (perhaps a main method?) that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet worked fine for me

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
         mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(set1);
        FilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("filter", filter).setFailOnUnknownId(false);
        ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(filterProvider);
        String writeValueAsString = writer.writeValueAsString(profile);
        Profile resultProfile = mapper.readValue(writeValueAsString,Profile.class);
```

Note: if you don't convert stringformat json to Profile.As mentioned in last 2 line of the code snippet then your response will be view as mentioned be

```
{\"name\":\"JPA in Use\",\"reviews\":[{\"id\...
```